# Does the name of a function defined in a friend declaration of a class have a linkage?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
class A{
   friend void fun(){} // #1
};
```

According to [dcl.meaning.general] p2

> If the declaration is a friend declaration:
>
> > - The declarator does not **bind** a name.

[basic.link] states that only *names* can have a linkage

> A name is said to have linkage when it can denote the same object, reference, function, type, template, namespace or value as a name introduced by a declaration in another scope.

`does not bind a name` seems not to mean it has no name. I wonder whether the name of the function defined in the friend declaration has a linkage or not.

Answer (score 2):

[class.friend] p4 specifies that point

> A function first declared in a friend declaration has the linkage of the namespace of which it is a member ([basic.link]). Otherwise, the function retains its previous linkage ([dcl.stc]).