# Can friend function of a local class be defined in namespace scope?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, friend, local-class

A local class in C++ can have friend functions, but these functions cannot be defined neither inside the class [[class.friend] p6](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.friend#6):

> A function may be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and only if the class is a non-local class and the function name is unqualified.

nor inside the enclosing function [[dcl.fct.def.general] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.general#2):

> [...] A function shall be defined only in namespace or class scope. [...]

But can friend function of a local class be defined in the global scope as follows:

```
auto foo() {
    struct A;
    void bar(const A&);
    struct A { 
        friend void bar(const A&);
    };
    bar(A{});
    return A{};
}

using A = decltype(foo());
void bar(const A&) {}
```

Both Clang and MSVC actually permit it, but GCC prints weird errors:

```
<source>:5:21: error: 'void bar(const foo()::A&)', declared using local type 'const foo()::A', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
    5 |         friend void bar(const A&);
      |                     ^~~
<source>:5:21: error: 'void bar(const foo()::A&)' used but never defined
<source>:12:6: warning: 'void bar(const A&)' defined but not used
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Yqoeda94x

Which compiler is correct here?

Comment: Use the scoping operator `::` to explicitly use the global namespace scope? As in `friend void ::bar(const A&);`

Comment: Such a code lacks of readability. What a practical usage does come to such a code?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude qualified and unqualified friend function names are covered by different rules

Comment: I think http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning.general#2.3 suggests the code is ok

Comment: @273K, thanks, friend functions is a practical thing, and it is not prohibited to declare friend functions for a local class, but I wonder what is readable way to define them.

Comment: I'm actually with GCC. The local A and ergo the friend has no linkage cause I ended up in https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#7 when trying to determine it - so it cannot match the namespace scope definition.

Comment: Then again, there's https://stackoverflow.com/a/71168429/817643 - But i'm not sure local classes were in mind here